# Platform to organize a giveaway on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I would like to give away 5 copies of my ebook to 5 random people who like my product's Facebook page before June *(or already liked my page and just enter the giveaway? or all fans? I am open to any similar rules)*.

[RaffleCopter](http://www.rafflecopter.com/) and [My Contests](https://apps.facebook.com/my-contests/) seem to do that, but with a few drawbacks:

- RaffleCopter seems to be a widget to embed in HTML. I would prefer a simple link, so that I can share it easily. Preferably a link that does not look too scary to the user (`http://facebook.com/giveaway/MyProduct` is OK, but `http://facebook.com/1941274?action=like&no_confirm=yes` and `http://heroku.biz/wqeofew` look scary)
- Both platforms advertise themselves to people who enter the giveaway. I am OK with a bit of advertisement, preferably not too much.

Requirements:

- Free
- Hosted (I have no server to host this)

Actually [this giveaway](http://www.vmwarearena.com/2014/05/prize-giveaway-5-lucky-winners-like-vmware-arena-and-win-a-334-pages-e-book-vmware-esxi-cookbook.html) looks acceptable to me (link, URL not too ad, no ads), but I don't know what platform they are using.

If Facebook had an official (non third-party) way to create giveaways, that would be the best.

Comment: I'm not aware of Facebook having its own giveaway service, so that's out of the question.

Comment: Handy document regarding promotions on pages: [Facebook Pages Terms - #Promotions](https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php#promotionsguidelines) - for when you've found a good tool

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using **[Woobox](https://woobox.com/)**. **Woobox** helps you easily create powerful contests, sweepstakes, coupons, and more to grow your fans and amplify your marketing. The benefit you can take:

- Grow your fanbase
- Spread your message
- Keep fans happy
- Own your fanbase

Woobox use url looks like `https://woobox.com/randomcharachter`. You can start it for free, I have nervous about advertisement informations. Sorry, If this recommendation was not suitable for your Facebook giveaway.